# WebdriverCurlException with php, selenium, and chromedriver

Tags: php, selenium, curl, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I run a series of tests using Facebook's PHP WebDriver and Selenium. I run them with phpunit on Chrome. The tests are run on a Windows machine, and the loaded pages are from a Ubuntu VM.

Most of the time, everything works great. However, every once in a while, the tests will error out spectacularly with several failing right at the start. The Chrome window opens, enters the desired url and... nothing. It 'loads' for about 30 seconds and then prints the following:

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http GET to /session/d86523c4-6b25-4e61-bc2c-bc0cd3e615f4/title

Operation timed out after 30000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

E:\dev\foldername\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Exception\WebDriverException.php:92
E:\dev\foldername\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.php:320
E:\dev\foldername\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.php:547
E:\dev\foldername\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.php:227
E:\dev\foldername\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\WebDriverExpectedCondition.php:60
E:\dev\foldername\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\WebDriverWait.php:60
E:\dev\foldername\tests\FunctionalTestBase.php:44
E:\dev\foldername\tests\ReorderQuestionsTest.php:18
```

It will also sometimes post this:

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http POST to /session/be8e5886-7d05-4eb5-a798-143fb7ed3b30/url with params: {"url":"http:\/\/app.name.test"}

Operation timed out after 30000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

E:\dev\foldername\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Exception\WebDriverException.php:92
E:\dev\foldername\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.php:320
E:\dev\foldername\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.php:547
E:\dev\foldername\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.php:195
E:\dev\foldername\tests\FunctionalTestBase.php:40
E:\dev\foldername\tests\TypeChangeWithRoute2Test.php:18
```

Using Phpunit 5.5.4, Php 7.0.10, Selenium server 2.53.1, Chromedriver 2.23, Chrome 53.0.2785.89.

Things I've tried:
Updating ChromeDriver to 2.9 (introduces a different problem, does not fix this one).
Adding a timeout after the $webDriver->get($this->url) call.
Adding this:

```
try{
    $this->webDriver->wait(5)->until(Condition::titleIs('Login'));
}catch(TimeOutException $e){
    $this->webDriver->get($this->url);
}
```

Starting the selenium server with right click->open with->java instead of command java -jar

I've found a mention of setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null but I can't seem to be able to find out where to add that.

My setup function:

```
$capabilities = Capabilities::chrome();
        $this->webDriver = Driver::create('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', $capabilities);
        $this->webDriver->manage()->window()->maximize();
        $this->webDriver->get($this->url);

        try{
            $this->webDriver->wait(2)->until(Condition::titleIs('Login'));
        }catch(TimeOutException $e){
            $this->webDriver->get($this->url);
        }
```

My teardown function:

```
$this->webDriver->quit();
```

I'm lost on what to do. I can't use a test that fails randomly.

I've also tried

```
try {
    $this->webDriver->get($this->url);
} catch (WebDriverCurlException $e) {
    $this->tearDown();
    $this->setUp();
}
```

UPDATE:
Well, I've got the same problem with Firefox, but not PhantomJS. I'm guessing there's something wrong with Selenium Server 2.53...

Comment: I have found that travis fails out like this when the network seems to be under heavy load. Just keep restarting the build, and it'll pass eventually when traffic slows down and resources free up.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the $request_timeout_in_ms as the 4th parameter when creating the client with Driver::create.
E.g.:

```
Driver::create('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', $capabilities, 60000, 60000);
```

will set the connection and the request timeout to 60 seconds.